# can ping but not ssh - eth0 lan

Tags: networking, routing, route

Stumped which direction to troubleshoot......

Server1 can ssh out to any computer but no other computer can ssh to Server1. Even if Server1 ssh to Server2 -> Server2 can not ssh back through same open ssh port to Server1.

> Server1 can ssh to Server3 then through ssh tunnel ssh to Server2

> > Server1=>Server3=>Server2

Why can Server1 tunnel to Server3 through Server2 but not through Server3 back to Server1?

> If connected by crossover cable Server1 can directly connect to Server2 but tunnel back to Server1 from Server2 is not possible.

> > Server1=>Server2=>[X]Server1

> > if connected to router

```
# ssh 192.168.4.1
# ssh: connect to host 192.168.4.1 port 22: Connection refused
```

```
# nc 192.168.4.1 22   (does not connect)
```

```
# nc -l 22  (on 192.168.4.1)
# nc: Address already in use
```

Server1: 192.168.4.2

Server2: 192.168.4.1

Server3: 192.168.4.3

> Firewall disabled for testing.  IP table accept all.  Suspect mis-configured routing table....

Server1 Kernel IP routing table

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

edit: reviewed old working saved " # route -n " outputs, metric for 192.168.4.0 (the subnet of the servers) is 100 .  Is it possible the metric setting displayed by route -n prevent ssh tunneling?

edit:

```
# tcpdump -c 25 -i eth0 -v
```

```
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
19:19:37.121131 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 19952, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 176)
    homie.ssh > 192.168.4.6.38360: Flags [P.], cksum 0x89fb (incorrect -> 0xecf8), seq 3089869718:3089869842, ack 4078834853, win 271, options [nop,nop,TS val 11868537 ecr 3677449774], length 124
19:19:37.121627 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 22362, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.4.6.38360 > homie.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0x8577 (correct), ack 124, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 3677449895 ecr 11868537], length 0
19:19:37.135066 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 19953, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 184)
    homie.ssh > 192.168.4.6.38360: Flags [P.], cksum 0x8a03 (incorrect -> 0xe8ff), seq 124:256, ack 1, win 271, options [nop,nop,TS val 11868540 ecr 3677449895], length 132
19:19:37.135254 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 37912, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 70)
    homie.57077 > gateway.domain: 17930+ PTR? 6.4.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (42)
19:19:37.135317 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 22363, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `sshd` is running on Server1? Can you `ssh localhost`?

Comment: # ssh localhost   (does work) sshd is running and ports are open in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: What is the output of `firewall-cmd --list-all`, and what account are you trying to use to log in with?

Comment: yes @cutrightjm firewalls were fine - dropped firewall to test but re-enabled and all packets arrived as expected.  thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

routes

```
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

1. can't have same subnet with two different netmasks
2. If two different subnets both point to same gateway 0.0.0.0 traffic bond for internal gw will get 'lost'

   `# sudo route del -net 192.168.4.0 gw 0.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0`

try now to use both networks separately.  route is auto-generated so it "may" work by itself.  if not, add route manually to remote ip (server), 192.168.4.0/24  does not seem to work, maybe someone can explain why....

```
`# route add -net 192.168.4.0 netmask 255.255.254.0 gw 192.168.4.2 eth0'
```

took a number of days to figure out the issue so posting here for my reference and maybe it will help someone with a similar problem looking for troubleshooting steps for ping but no ssh.